# java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index with jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am passing `jsessionid` with request. Sample request: 
`http://www.abc.org.in/appln/demoRequest;jsessionid=${Jsessionid}`

I am getting the following exception: `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index`. The index at which the exception occurred is that of `=`.

How do I solve for this?

Comment: at the time you get that exception, what `${Jsessionid}` is resolved as?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe JMeter complains on `=` character, it is being used as parameter/value separator all the time.

[image: equal sign in URL]

However `$` sign is not allowed in URLs as per [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) so my expectation is that the logic you use to extract JSESSIONID into the variable is failing.

Given [JSESSIONID](http://www.cs-repository.info/2014/07/understanding-jsessionid.html) in majority of cases is a [HTTP Cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), you could use [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) like:

1. Configure HTTP Cookie Manager to store cookies as JMeter Variables. In order to do it add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up
2. Once HTTP Cookie Manager extracts the cookie you should be able to access it where required as `${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}` like:

   http://www.abc.org.in/appln/demoRequest;jsessionid=${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}

---

In the unlikely case of JSESSIONID not being a cookie you can handle it with the [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_URL_Re-writing_Modifier).